# AngularJS Display Preloader - Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i want to display a preloader while the website is loading. The problem is that my other content appears before the preloader dom has loaded. The preloader appears after the whole dom has loaded. I want that the preloader shows up before everything else.
Here is my directive:

```
function() {
        "use strict";
        angular.module("App").directive("preloader", ["$timeout", "$window", "$q", function(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                templateUrl: "views/preloader.html",
                replace: !0,          
            }
        }])
    }.call(this),
```

& preloader.html

```
<div id="preloader">
    <div class='logo'>

    </div>
</div>
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="App">

    <div preloader></div>

    <main class="main" ui-view=""></main>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance, i appreciate any help and solution you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your preloader directly in the `<main>HERE...</main>`, it will be replaced when the view is loaded.

Look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YWM6ekV7kDKXKCvTmCYa?p=preview), you can see briefly "Preloader..." before the view content is loaded.

Comment: i need the preloader for the whole page not only for <main> i have other things on the site too.

Comment: Then maybe you can take a look at [angular-page-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-page-loader), [here](https://codekraft.it/demos/angular-page-loader/example/default/#/) is a demo of it

Answer (score 0):

You can call an initialize function on you `body` tag of index.html like this.

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-init="myInitFunction()">

<div preloader></div>

<main class="main" ui-view=""></main>
```

And in `myInitFunction()` write your code to call your loader.

I hope this works for you